# Postgres: How to use COPY FROM WITH DELIMITER with CHR function?

Tags: postgresql

I try to import a text file into a single column table, i.e. I don't want a single line of the source file to be delimited into columns. The file contains many different characters (tabs, commas, spaces) that could be recognized as delimiters. Since *bell* (`CHR(7)`) doesn't exist in the data file I chose it as delimiter:

```
COPY data_table(single_column) FROM '/tmp/data' WITH ENCODING 'LATIN1' DELIMITER CHR(7);
```

Unfortunately, this results in an error:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "chr"

What would be the correct syntax?

Comment: which version of postgresql are you using?

Comment: `psql --version` returns _psql (PostgreSQL) 13.4 (Ubuntu 13.4-0ubuntu0.21.04.1)_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a function there. Use the escape notation.

```
 DELIMITER E'\007'
```

Comment: Thank you! That's much better than using a hex editor to get the _bell_ character into the script...